# Injecting beans in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a Session scoped bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ficheCultureActionController")
@SessionScoped
public class FicheCultureActionController implements Serializable {}
```

I want to injected in two other beans.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "semenceActionController")
@ViewScoped
public class SemenceActionController implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{ficheCultureActionController}")
    private FicheCultureActionController ficheCultureActionController;

    public FicheCultureActionController getFicheCultureActionController() {
        return ficheCultureActionController;
    }

    public void setFicheCultureActionController(FicheCultureActionController ficheCultureActionController) {
        this.ficheCultureActionController = ficheCultureActionController;
    }

    public List<SemenceAction> getListSemenceParFicheCulture() {
        if (ficheCultureActionController.getSelected() != null) {
            listSemenceParFicheCulture = getFacade().getSemenceParFicheCulture();
        }
        return listSemenceParFicheCulture;
    }
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean(name = "engraisActionController")
@ViewScoped
public class EngraisActionController implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{ficheCultureActionController}")
    private FicheCultureActionController ficheCultureActionController;

    public FicheCultureActionController getFicheCultureActionController() {
        return ficheCultureActionController;
    }

    public void setFicheCultureActionController(FicheCultureActionController ficheCultureActionController) {
        this.ficheCultureActionController = ficheCultureActionController;
    }
}
```

but the property returns `null` in the method `getListSemenceParFicheCulture()`.

Comment: yes i did the getter and setter

Comment: yes i have null in ficheCultureActionController.getSelected()

Comment: if i use FicheCultureActionController  only in one bean it works but if i used in the two bean FicheCultureActionController return null in the second

Comment: I found a solution, we must put @ViewScoped on beans where I will inject the first bean